# Leaking passing data using delegate in a background thread

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm trying to pass some data from one `controller` to another after some calculations are finished, however I am getting this `memory leaks` on `Instruments`, both is part of the same leak just in different part of the call stack.

Passing the data by `delegate`:

[image]
Saving it to `parse.com`:

[image]

Comment: What is the leaked object?

Comment: @jtbandes Sorry I am just starting with Instruments I am trying to figure out how to get that information, I was under the impression the leak was the highlight lines.

Comment: The leak may *occur at* the highlighted lines, but from looking at them I'm not sure what the leaked object is. Can you post a more full screenshot of what Instruments shows? (I agree it's hard to understand much of the time.)

Comment: @jtbandes I add the main one, there are so many I don't know if this is the one you need